# Renaming destination file without using Rename in NSIS script

Tags: nsis

If I have file being copied using the following

```
SetOutPath "$FOO_DIR"
File "..\..\Bar.Dat"

...

SetOutPath "$OTHER_FOO_DIR"
File "..\..\Bar.Dat"
```

Note that the file *Bar.Dat* is supposed to be copied to other locations later on to during the installation. How do I rename it for this specific copy operation? If I do a *Rename* on it the later operations will not find it. I have been looking for an option to pass a *destination file name* to the *File* operation, but can't find one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course I managed to find the answer straight after posting this question. ****smack****

*File* does in fact take a flag of the destination name.

```
 File "..\..\Bar.Dat" /oname="DestinationNameOfFile.Dat"
```

Comment: quote the entire parameter, including /oname, i.e. `File "/oname=DestinationNameOfFile.Dat" "..\..\Bar.Dat"`

Answer (score 12):

Actually tried the above but the nsis compiler complains. 
a little bit of rearranging would make it work:

```
File /oname="DestinationNameOfFile.Dat" "..\..\Bar.Dat"
```

*the source filename is the 2nd argument for /oname

Comment: Which version of NSIS did you use? The way I described worked in 2.46.

Comment: oh yeah! forgot to check about that one. i'm using 2.46.

Comment: I had an error when using this with quotes. Removing the quotes from the destination file name fixed it. Version 2.46

Comment: If the output name contains spaces, quote the entire parameter, including /oname, i.e.: `File "/oname=nome with spaces.txt" "Original name.txt"`